# How to write data to an excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I have some data that I'd like to save in an excel file.  How does one do this in python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a great python module called [XLWT](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt). I'd recommend using that... it writes native Excel files instead of CSVs. Supports formulas, etc too.

[Documentation](http://www.python-excel.org/) (borrowed from Mark)

Answer (score 5):

I'll answer a slightly different question: "How can I write data so that Excel can read it?"

Use the `csv` module to write your data as a .csv file, and then open it in Excel.

```
import csv
csvout = csv.writer(open("mydata.csv", "wb"))
csvout.writerow(("Country", "Year"))
for coutry, year in my_data_iterable():
    csvout.writerow((country, year))
```

Comment: Note: this works, but in some locales (particularly where the decimal comma ',' is used instead of the decimal dot '.'), you'll need to use different separators (semicolons, for example).

Comment: @Poskvor: Maybe you know this, but I'll state it for the general good.  The delimiter can be changed by using a Dialect.  See http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a BIFF8 XLS file, I would use the [excellent xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Answer (score 0):

if it's running on windows, try creating an instance of `EXCEL.APPLICATION` via [COM](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html)

Use Excel Help for the object reference.

This way you can even format the data, write formulas, etc.

Comment: I assumed it is installed, because the question was explicit about Excel.

Comment: yeah but the question was about an excel file, not using the excel application.