# Can Python selenium be used to work with Excel sheet to store webdata?

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Can I use python to work with Excel?Basically I will traverse the webpage and collect the data from the different fields and want to store them in excel tabular format.So is there any way to open an excel and act with the cells as per needed to store web data dynamically?

I am using python 2.7 and selenium.

Thanks,

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Writing to Excel 2007+ files (.xlsx files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257771/python-writing-to-excel-2007-files-xlsx-files)

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can do that.

See below posts

[How to write data to an excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133142/how-to-write-data-to-an-excel-file)

[Python: Writing to Excel 2007+ files (.xlsx files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257771/python-writing-to-excel-2007-files-xlsx-files)